# Windows & Linux [UEFI triple boot issues]

Tags: windows, grub, uefi

So I installed my OSes, three in total, in UEFI successfully. At least, I think so. They boot and work. The problem is, the grub menu no longer functions the way that it did on Legacy BIOS mode.

Before I was presented a purple menu where I could scroll down to select Ubuntu, Windows 7 or Windows 10 + a folder to select other Ubuntu options. It would boot immediately into whatever I selected.

Now though, I'm presented with a grub menu that looks the same but doesn't function the same. Instead of other options (besides Ubuntu at least), I have a whole bunch of weird options like Windows Bootloader and Windows boot.efi etc.

If I click into any of the Windows related options, it will take me to Windows 10's blue screen to select Windows 10 or 7. Now here's the problem. It doesn't immediately go into the OS I selected it takes me back to the purple menu screen via a reboot and I have to select any of the Windows options **again** for it to load into whatever Windows OS that I picked.

So, what could be the problem here? I tried boot-repair and followed its instructions, but the problem persists.

The steps I took for my triple boot UEFI installs was this: Change BIOS to UEFI > create Windows USB devices with Rufus GPT  support > install Windows 7 > install Windows 10 > install Ubuntu 16.04 > Boot-Repair > Change in BIOS to boot off the Ubuntu drive as BR suggested (thought it said to boot off of bootXX.efi sdX). All OSes are installed on their own HDDs, by the way.

Is there any way to fix this problem? Did I do something wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for two days now and it has been hopeless.

edit

I can get some screenshots if it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I didn't want to revert to BIOS/Legacy, as I wanted the UEFI benefits, so I was determined and googled various minor solutions that led me to my overall solution. I posted the full steps on the ubuntu forums.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384848&p=13739574#post13739574

Hopefully this will help people! :)

Answer (score 0):

Separate drives actually complicates this somewhat, but shouldn't be a problem.

You can troubleshoot the Windows bootloader using a Windows install or repair DVD (or USB, but I found burning the DVD and knowing it would work better than making the USB work and then needing it on a rig that can't boot from USB); pretty bog-standard stuff you can Google your way through.

More difficult is Grub. Repairing Grub would be just difficult enough -- requiring mounting your EFI partition(s) with write access, and most likely unable to navigate via GUI -- that I would recommend just booting to Ubuntu and installing [rEFInd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REFInd).

You will have to boot to rEFInd at least once, and if you keep installing OSes you might have to find it again, but it automatically restores itself being the primary boot manager when loaded and it scans for bootloaders on boot (so no need to point to them).

You will have to figure out which bootloaders to use (Windows should only show one or two in rEFInd; for Ubuntu look for grub or syslinux), though you can then hide the extras. If they bother you enough to hide them I would look into the documentation to do so via rEFInd's config, rather than the easy-but-dirty method used within the manager itself.

Comment: Hello! 

If I tried this method, would it fix needing to boot twice whenever I select a Windows OS?